# Matplotlib app to open and close multiple plot windows from a main plot window

Tags: python, matplotlib

A long time ago I coded a GUI with `matplotlib` that despite the complicated code it does what I expect it to do it. If I would re-write now I would change the entire logic behind it, but I cannot afford it now. I have a very last feature that I would like to add, but I'm stuck.

Basically I have the main plot that when pressing a button calls a class. This class opens a second plot where I do some stuff and then I close it. After closing it I need to access the attributes of this class that have been defined by interacting with the second plot. However, when I try to access the attributes I get a NameError.

This is a minimal code that recreates the issue I have. If you run it, then press 'Ok' on the first plot, then 'Ok' on the second plot and finally 'Next' on the first plot you will get the NameError.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

img = np.zeros((600,600))
ax_b = plt.axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
ok_b = Button(ax_b, 'Ok')
ax_next = plt.axes([0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
next_b = Button(ax_next, 'Next')


class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
        ax_b_1 = plt.axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
        ok_b_1 = Button(ax_b_1, 'Ok')
        ok_b_1.on_clicked(self.ok1)
        ax1.imshow(img)
        plt.show()

    def ok1(self, event):
        self.a = 3
        plt.close(self.fig1)

def ok(event):
    global b
    b = foo()
    print('Figure one closed')

def next(event):
    print(b.a)
    print('Next')

ok_b.on_clicked(ok)
next_b.on_clicked(next)

ax.imshow(img)
plt.show()
print(b.a)
print('End')
```

Basically when I press `ok_b` button on the main plot the event linked to it calls the class `foo` that is assigned to a variable called `b` and creates/open a new plot. When I press `ok_b_1` an on the second plot I assign some attributes to the `foo` class and then I call `plt.close()` and the second plot gets closed properly. The idea would be to go back to the main plot which is still open and upon pressing `next` I would like to access `foo` attributes but I get a NamedError (see below) even if I have `global b` in the function `ok` called by `ok_b`. The thing is that if I close the main window as well the attribute of `b` actually is accessible and gets properly printed.

After pressing `next`:

```
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

After closing the main window:

```
Figure one closed
3
End
```

Does anybody now a quick way to fix this without changing the logic too much? Thank you very much, and apologies in advanced for the complicated logic that I know I should change.

NOTE: I have Python 3.7.4 - 64 bit with matplotlib 3.1.2 on Windows 10 64bit.

EDIT WORKING ALTERNATIVE:
Basically I just had to move the connection to the button on_clicked event and plt.show() outside of **init** method. I guess it's becuase somewhere it gets stuck into **init** and it doesn't exit, I don't actually now. The following should work:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
        ax_b_1 = plt.axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
        self.ok_b_1 = Button(ax_b_1, 'Ok')
        ax1.imshow(img)

    def ok1(self, event):
        self.a = 3
        plt.close(self.fig1)

def ok(event):
    global b
    b = foo()
    b.ok_b_1.on_clicked(b.ok1)
    plt.show()
    print('Figure one closed')

def next(event):
    print(b.a)
    print('Next')

ok_b.on_clicked(ok)
next_b.on_clicked(next)

ax.imshow(img)
plt.show()
print(b.a)
print('End')
```

WORKING SOLUTION 2:

Since it's not recommended to call multiple plt.show() before having closed all the windows opened by the previous call of plt.show() in order to handle multiple plot windows it's better to embed them in a tkinter window. In this way to close secondary plots we can call tkinter methods root.quit() AND root.destroy() as per matplotlib official tutorial

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html

Comment: Ok found the solution! I will add it as a comment for whoever will encouter the same issue

Comment: I added two solutions that I found, the second one is best in my opinion